# Chrome web browser doesn't keep me signed in

Tags: google-chrome

```
ghopper@TM1701 ~ $ uname -a
Linux TM1701 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ghopper@TM1701 ~ $ google-chrome-stable --version
Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100
```

Every time I start the browser I get "paused" status for my account. gmail.com website doesn't recognize me too, but `github.com`, `stackoverflow.com` etc work fine!

[image: sign in request]

Then I type the password and everythig works fine until I close the browser.

### Extensions:

- Adblock Plus
- Google Docs Offline
- Keyboard Shortcuts for Google Translate
- MultiPass for HTTP basic authentication
- Vue.js devtools
- Xdebug helper

### Chrome Apps:

- Docs
- Sheets
- Slides

How to force `chrome` keep me signed in?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, but I not sure how I made it. Here a few  steps I have made:

1. `Chrome Menu` -> `Settings` -> `Passwords` and purge "Never Saved" section.
2. `Chrome Menu` -> `Settings` -> `Advanced` -> `Allow Chrome sign-in` turn it on
3. `Chrome Menu` -> `Settings` -> `Advanced` -> `Content settings` -> `Cookies` -> `Keep local data only until you quit your browser` turn it off and purge `Block` and `Clear on exit` sections.